# Zapya and linux

Tags: linux, networking, wifi

I've search for a version of Zapya for linux but can't seem to find one.

Is there any way to share files between my android device and my linux box similar to how Zapya works?

What alternative could I use to accomplish this without using bluetooth or a USB connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Syncthing](https://syncthing.net/) to manage files on my mobile devices.
When it's set up, managing the files is done with your file manager.

There are other similar solutions, but this one covers my needs.

Comment: I got the following error when following the instructions to install on my linux box    `E: Failed to fetch https://apt.syncthing.net/dists/syncthing/stable/binary-amd64/Packages  Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT`

Comment: Have not gotten it to work on my mint box but at least it's working with my mobile devices. Thanks @mioriin